# mongodb error parsing yaml config file

Tags: mongodb, config

I've got a problem with mongodb. After upgrade from 2.6 I had to change config file - here's the new one:

```
storage:  
    dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb"  
    engine: wiredTiger  

systemLog:  
    destination: file  
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"  
    logAppend: true  

net:  
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.14.81
    port: 27017  
    # Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).  
    http:  
        enabled: false
```

But startup script crashes - here's the output:

```
Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 5, column 5: end of map not found
try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
```

I'm using only white symbols (spaces - not tabs). Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with that conf?

Answer (score 8):

Firstly try to validate your YAML file whether It is valid or not using any tool or online website for eg. http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and try to resolve the issues because I already faced the same Issue.

In my case problem was in Tab character. I checked it during validation process of YAML file Then I replaced the Tab character with the space character and replaced the single slashes() with double(\) then everything worked fine.

**My config file as:**

```
systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: "c:\\data\\log"
storage:
 dbPath: "c:\\data\\db"
```

Comment: Excellent friend, this was the problem, for some reason in the installation that yml got a failure